# Unable to commit/import code from SVN repository :Error : svn: warning: W205000: Ignoring unknown value

Tags: svn, pycharm

I am using Pycharm for my robot framework code.
Was working fine in the past ...now suddenly unable to commit/import code as i am getting

Error : svn: warning: W205000: Ignoring unknown value........

Answer (score 1):

It is a `Proxy` issue.

I had the same issue in IntelliJ IDEA and it was very frustrated.
A weird thing was that I could commit or update my project through IDE, but I couldn't refresh the repository's logs (I have no idea how could this happened)

After some investigation it turned out that my problem was that my system was behind a **proxy**, and Subversion plugin couldn't inherit it for some operations.

To resolve your issue try the following (**Assumming you are in Windows**):

- From IntelliJ go to *File → Settings → Version Control → Subversion → Network* and make sure checkbox *"Use IDEA general proxy...."* is **NOT CHECKED**
- From IntelliJ go to *File → Settings → Version Control → Subversion* and make sure checkbox *"Use custom configuration directory"* is **CHECKED** and point to the directory *$USER_HOME\AppData\Roaming\Subversion*
- In directory *$USER_HOME\AppData\Roaming\Subversion*, there should be a `servers.txt` file. Go ahead and edit it, and set under **[global]** the `http-proxy-host` and `http-proxy-port` settings accordingly

After that, you should be able to commit/update/refresh fetch repository logs etc..